# Can’t understand this Fibonacci python program

Tags: python, fibonacci

I’m new at this and I’m trying my best to really understand everything that is happening in every code I learn to do. I could manage to write this code by the websites explaining how to do it, but still, I can’t understand what happens in the end after ‘while counter < nterms. I know we are creating a loop there and also an equation that will make the Fibonacci sequence to happen, but I wonder if someone would have the patience to break it down for me? Thank you in advance. I don’t want to do labs only for the grades, I really want to learn with them.

```
 nterms = int(input("Please enter a positive integer greater than 1: "))


n1, n2 = 1, 1
count = 0


if nterms == 1:
   print(nterms)
   print(n1)
else:
   while count < nterms:
       print(n1)
       nth = n1 + n2
       n1 = n2
       n2 = nth
       count += 1
```

Comment: What's unclear? Are you familiar with the definition of the Fibonacci sequence? The usual Python idiom would be somewhat more succinct, as (unlikely in some other languages) you can avoid the temporary variable.

Comment: It's a direct implementation of the series. `n1` and `n2` are the prior two terms. At each iteration of the loop, the sum of the prior two terms is computers and then the new "two prior" are rotated into place.

Comment: Your counter "count" is increased of one at each iteration of the while loop. The loop stops when count == nterms.  At each iteration, you do the maths of Fibonacci sequence: n1+n2 go into temporary variable nth, n2 goes into n1, nth into n2

Comment: If it's no obvious, just get a piece of paper to record the values of n1, n2, count, nterms, and nth and execute it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

do you know fibonacci? `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55`

can you formulate this? ... ummmm... from 3rd number, every number is sum of two previous numbers: `F_n = F_n-1 + F_n-2`

now, you have 2 first numbers: `1, 1`, and you must get all other numbers... how? simply sum them and create new `variable`...:

`nth = n1 + n2`

now, your new number is `2`, and you have 3 numbers `[1,1,2]`

notice you can do it and make new numbers forever... but, from fibo formula, you know that for define a new number, you just need 2 previous...

so, shift all your numbers and remove first number in these 3 numbers and hold just 2nd and 3rd numbers:
`[1, 1, 2] => [1, 2]`

```
   n1 = n2
   n2 = n3
```

a very simple point: if you don't define a new variable, `n3`, you can't shift number, because...

assume you set `n2 = n1 + n2` then you don't have your second variable for shift: `n1 = n2` and you miss your second variable...

---

if you know about `list`, you can use a `list`:

```
fibo = [1, 1]
for i in range(nterms - 2):
    fibo.append(fibo[-1] + fibo[-2])
```

also, python has a tricky way for shift:

```
for i in range(nterms):
    print(n1)
    n1, n2 = n2, n1 + n2
```

please note that you print first element, `n1`, in each iteration, so you don't need `if` part and every number that was shifted to `n1`, it will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

A Fibonacci sequence is a series of numbers in which any number is the sum of the previous two numbers (except for the first two in the series) like 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ... Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).
The program prints the number `n1`, creates a temporary variable (`nth`, which is the sum of the previous two numbers), and sets `n1` to the value of `n2`, and sets `n2` to the value of the temporary variable `nth`. This moves both `n1` and `n2` up one value in the sequence. It increments `count` so that after printing as many numbers as the user entered, it exits.

Answer (score 0):

Fibonacci sequence always begins with 1, 1. If you enter 1, the sequence is already complete. That's the if statement.

The while loop will print the first number.
Then, with a temporary variable (nth), it will calculate the next number in the sequence (3rd in the sequence on the first loop).
Now it will move n2 into n1 and store the result (in the temporary variable 'nth') in n2.

for example, if you entered 4:

First loop:

```
print (n1) #(1)
nth = (n1 + n2) #(2)
n1 = n2 #(1)
n2 = nth #(2)
count += 1 #(3)
```

This will display: 1 and store 1 in `n1` and 2 in `n2`.

The next loop will display 1, then store 1 + 2 in `nth`, then 2 in `n1` and `nth` (or 3) in `n2`. The count will now be 2.

The next loop will display 2, then store 2 + 3 in `nth`, then 3 in `n1` and `nth` (or 5) in `n2`. The count will now be 3

And it will keep going until the count variable is the same as the initial integer entered by the user.

In this case, the last loop will display 3, which is stored in `n1`, and that will be the end of it as the count will no longer be less than `nterms`.

Happy to clear this up more if I can.